# Navigation Drawer toggle button not working only when swiped across is working

Tags: java, android

I do have placed the navigation drawer icon on the action bar and it certainly is showing up, but upon click on the drawer icon the function is not happening, only upon swipe the navigation drawer is opening.

**ArticleActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_article);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.progress);
    mFullContainerView = findViewById(R.id.full_container);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
```

**activity_article.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_article_drawer" />


        <include layout="@layout/list_view" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: did you override `onOptionsItemSelected()`?

Comment: yes i did add that also & it is working

Comment: glad it worked for you. please post your changes as self answer so it can be helpful for future use.

Comment: no no what i meant was, whatever the code which i gave in the onOptionsItemSelected is working but my issue is that the navigation drawer is in not opening up when i'm clicking the navigation drawer icon

Comment: are you using theme with default toolbar or you are using custom toolbar?

Comment: a custom toolbar

Comment: check the answer I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks like you are using your custom toolbar as actionbar, But you have not set it as support actionbar. You need to use `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` to set your custom toolbar as actionbar.

```
 Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Also, make sure you are extending your application main theme from theme with no actionbar.

Comment: If i set my theme as no action bar then the drawer icon is not popping up